# How to sort LinearLayout's children programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have Linear Layout with horizontal orientation which has few ImageViews in it (hardcoded in the xml). I have to sort them based on MultiselectListPreference (all the checked first and unchecked later). To put checked ones in the beginning I tried

```
((LinearLayout)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView);
((LinearLayout)imageView.getParent()).addView(imageView,0);
```

And did nothing with unchecked. But it gives me the "The specified child already exists. You must call removeView(view) on view's given parent" though I've already called it. This may be because all those ImageViews are present in xml. How can I obtain the desired arrangement of child ImageViews. If at all LinearLayout does not suffice, should I use RecyclerView here , would it be heavier?

Comment: I definitely think anytime you're talking about reordering views you're better off with a RecyclerView or ListView of some type.  They're made for this sort of work, and won't incur the large cost of multiple relayouts.

Comment: I'm confused as how `imageView.getParent()` would work if you just had just removed `imageView` from the parent view....

Comment: @GabeSechan I will dwell on Recycler henceforth.

Comment: @cricket_007  -  even I'm confused but this is the solution I found for sorting. May be it works because though the view is removed from Parent, the object  'imageView' still  holds its parent's info in its 'parent' field or so.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cast the parent view to **ViewGroup** so the **removeView** method will work.

```
((ViewGroup)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView);
```

Comment: He's already casting it to a LinearLayout, which is a child of ViewGroup.  This won't fix anything.

Comment: Indeed it fixed my problem. Even I'm amazed. @GabeSechan I suggest you upvote it back.

Comment: Could optimize this a bit so you are getting a ViewGroup object instead of calling getParent() and casting each time, but this should work. No idea why casting as a LinearLayout didn't work.. time to dig up source code

Comment: Have you updated both lines from LinearLayouts to ViewGroup? If "yes" I will update my answer to explain why it works @fanatic

Comment: @AliSheikhpour
No. Good that you asked. I changed only it only for removeView. I had  to do something like

`linearLayout=(LinearLayout)imageView.getParent();
((ViewGroup)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView);
linearLayout.addView(imageView,linearLayout.getChildCount());`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour - please explain anyway

Comment: Even you removeChild from parent, the child remembers its parents info yet. So child.getParent().AddView() will fail. Casting the parent to ViewGroup or creating a new instance of parent (like your last comment) solves the problem.